# How to copy textbox values over in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nLMPe/3/

Is there something like `.html()` which will also copy the values from textboxes with user-inputted values in them?

I will be possible working with massive amounts of textboxes, so `.val()` for each individual textbox is not a practical solution.

--looking for a `.html()` alternative that also copies values from textboxes and textareas

Comment: this line was just added right? _" will be possible working with massive amounts of textboxes, so .val() for each individual textbox is not a practical solution."_

Comment: Sorry, i just added it in case people didn't open the jsFiddle.

Comment: So your wanting a common "get value" method and "set value" method? You should rephrase your question it is difficult to understand what you want

Comment: I'm wondering if there is an alternative to `.html()` which will also copy over user-inputted values on textboxes and textareas.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you should use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for form elements.

Comment: @m.t.bennett, horrible idea, it will not track user changes.

Comment: Removed as it was not what he's looking for anyway